# How to access health data from React Native

Tags: react-native, health-monitoring

I was wondering if you can check the user's health data without a smart watch and just the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an NPM package available to do just this. Haven't used it though.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-health

Comment: Thanks but to get data like heart beat, etc, the user needs to have a smartwatch